# AngularJS ng-repeat radio buttons aren't checked by default

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to check the first index, but it isn't working. I also tried to do this with ng-init.

```
 <div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="category in categories">
        <label>
       {{category.Name}}

     <input type="radio" ng-checked="$index==0?true" name="pageNumber" ng-model="$parent.pageNumber" ng-value="category.Name" />
    </label>
  </div>
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: `$index==0?true` doesn't seem like a valid expression to me. Have you tried just `$index == 0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ngChecked shouldnot be used with ngModel (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked)

You can try this

```
<input type="radio" name="pageNumber" ng-model="$parent.pageNumber" ng-value="category.Name" />
</label>
```

and when the categories get populated in you controller you can add the following code after that

```
$scope.pageNumber = $scope.categories[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following expression `$index==0?true:false` or simply `$index==0`

Answer (score 0):

You can simple write `ng-checked="$first"`

```
  <div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="category in categories">
        <label>
       {{category.Name}} - {{$index}} -
       <input type="radio" ng-checked="$first">
    </label>
  </div>
```

**Example** http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/8864/

Answer (score 0):

**`ngChecked`** is expecting an `expression`, so by saying `ng-checked="$index == 0"`, you're basically saying that the `checkbox` will always be checked or unchecked by default based on the condition output.

remove `ng-value` as you can also pass the element data using `ng-model`.

**Working fiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/LYuCG/16/